# _pickle.UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered, but no persistent_load function was specified. in kypt_trans demo file

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to run demo file in kypt transformer(https://github.com/shreyashampali/kypt_transformer) and I followed the directions in that page but I got an error in following code

$ python demo.py --ckpt_path '/home/my_id/Downloads/interhand_pkl/data.pkl' --use_big_decoder --dec_layers 6

```
(kypt_trans) my_id@my_id:~/anaconda3/envs/kypt_trans/kypt_transformer/main$ python demo.py --ckpt_path '/home/my_id/Downloads/interhand_pkl/data.pkl' --use_big_decoder --dec_layers 6
WARNING: You are using a MANO model, with only 10 shape coefficients.
WARNING: You are using a MANO model, with only 10 shape coefficients.
>>> Using GPU: 0
02-25 17:06:18 Creating test dataset...
Load annotation from  /home/my_id/Downloads/InterHand/annotations/all
loading annotations into memory...
Done (t=18.16s)
creating index...
index created!
Get bbox and root depth from groundtruth annotation
WARNING: You are using a MANO model, with only 10 shape coefficients.
WARNING: You are using a MANO model, with only 10 shape coefficients.
 86%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▌             | 730848/849160 [02:20<00:20, 5683.35it/s]Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81196 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
 87%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▏            | 736243/849160 [02:21<00:19, 5692.77it/s]Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
Frame 81106 in capture Id 2 does not have MANO model (skipping)...
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 849160/849160 [02:41<00:00, 5251.22it/s]
Number of annotations in single hand sequences: 488968
Number of annotations in interacting hand sequences: 360050
02-25 17:09:20 Load checkpoint from /home/my_id/Downloads/interhand_pkl/data.pkl
02-25 17:09:20 Creating graph...
BackboneNet No. of Params = 23508032
decoder_net No. of Params = 69568001
transformer No. of Params = 17363968
Init of peak detector took 0.082735 s
WARNING: You are using a MANO model, with only 10 shape coefficients.
WARNING: You are using a MANO model, with only 10 shape coefficients.
WARNING: You are using a MANO model, with only 10 shape coefficients.
WARNING: You are using a MANO model, with only 10 shape coefficients.
Total No. of Params = 117045476
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 347, in <module>
    main()
  File "demo.py", line 71, in main
    tester._make_model()
  File "/home/my_id/anaconda3/envs/kypt_trans/kypt_transformer/common/base.py", line 208, in _make_model
    ckpt = torch.load(model_path)
  File "/home/my_id/anaconda3/envs/kypt_trans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 608, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/home/my_id/anaconda3/envs/kypt_trans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 777, in _legacy_load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered,
but no persistent_load function was specified.
```

how can I solve this problem?

here is my current state of package

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
absl-py                   2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
addict                    2.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
aiofiles                  22.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
aiosqlite                 0.20.0                   pypi_0    pypi
alsa-lib                  1.2.3.2              h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
anyio                     3.7.1                    pypi_0    pypi
argon2-cffi               23.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0           py38h7f8727e_0  
arrow                     1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
asttokens                 2.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
async-lru                 2.0.4            py38h06a4308_0  
attrs                     23.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
babel                     2.14.0                   pypi_0    pypi
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.12.3                   pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl    conda-forge
bleach                    6.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
blinker                   1.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
bottleneck                1.3.7            py38ha9d4c09_0  
brotli                    1.0.9                h5eee18b_7  
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h5eee18b_7  
brotli-python             1.0.9            py38h6a678d5_7  
bzip2                     1.0.8                hd590300_5    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.27.0               hd590300_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2024.2.2             hbcca054_0    conda-forge
cachetools                4.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2024.2.2         py38h06a4308_0  
cffi                      1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        2.0.12                   pypi_0    pypi
chumpy                    0.70                     pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
comm                      0.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
configargparse            1.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
cudatoolkit               11.3.1              hb98b00a_13    conda-forge
curl                      8.2.1                h37d81fd_0  
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
cython                    3.0.8            py38h5eee18b_0  
dash                      2.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
dash-core-components      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
dash-html-components      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
dash-table                5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
dbus                      1.13.18              hb2f20db_0  
debugpy                   1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
deprecation               2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.4              py38h06a4308_0  
exceptiongroup            1.2.0            py38h06a4308_0  
executing                 2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
expat                     2.5.0                h6a678d5_0  
fastjsonschema            2.19.1                   pypi_0    pypi
ffmpeg                    4.3                  hf484d3e_0    pytorch
flask                     3.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
fontconfig                2.13.1               h6c09931_0  
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
fqdn                      1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
freetype                  2.12.1               h267a509_2    conda-forge
freetype-py               2.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
gettext                   0.21.0               hf68c758_0  
glib                      2.68.4               h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.68.4               h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
gmp                       6.3.0                h59595ed_0    conda-forge
gnutls                    3.6.13               h85f3911_1    conda-forge
google-auth               1.35.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.62.0                   pypi_0    pypi
gst-plugins-base          1.14.5               h0935bb2_2    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.18.5               h76c114f_0    conda-forge
icu                       68.1                 h2531618_0  
idna                      3.6                      pypi_0    pypi
imageio                   2.34.0                   pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        7.0.1            py38h06a4308_0  
importlib_metadata        7.0.1                hd3eb1b0_0  
importlib_resources       6.1.1            py38h06a4308_1  
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          h06a4308_3561  
ipykernel                 6.17.1                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   8.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython-genutils          0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipywidgets                8.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
isoduration               20.11.0                  pypi_0    pypi
itsdangerous              2.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.19.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jinja2                    3.1.3            py38h06a4308_0  
joblib                    1.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9e                   h0b41bf4_3    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.17                   pypi_0    pypi
jsonpointer               2.4                      pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                4.21.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema-specifications 2023.12.1                pypi_0    pypi
jupyter                   1.0.0            py38h06a4308_9  
jupyter-client            7.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-events            0.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-lsp               2.2.0            py38h06a4308_0  
jupyter-packaging         0.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server            1.24.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server-fileid     0.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server-terminals  0.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server-ydoc       0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-ydoc              0.2.5                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_client            8.6.0            py38h06a4308_0  
jupyter_console           6.6.3            py38h06a4308_0  
jupyter_core              5.5.0            py38h06a4308_0  
jupyter_events            0.8.0            py38h06a4308_0  
jupyter_server            2.10.0           py38h06a4308_0  
jupyter_server_terminals  0.4.4            py38h06a4308_1  
jupyterlab                3.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-pygments       0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-server         2.16.3                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-widgets        3.0.10                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0  
jupyterlab_server         2.25.1           py38h06a4308_0  
jupyterlab_widgets        3.0.9            py38h06a4308_0  
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.2            py38h295c915_0  
krb5                      1.20.1               hf9c8cef_0    conda-forge
lame                      3.100             h166bdaf_1003    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.15                 hfd0df8a_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1  
lerc                      4.0.0                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h5eee18b_7  
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h5eee18b_7  
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h5eee18b_7  
libclang                  11.1.0          default_ha53f305_1    conda-forge
libclang13                14.0.6          default_he11475f_1  
libcups                   2.4.2                ha637b67_0  
libcurl                   8.2.1                h91b91d3_0  
libdeflate                1.17                 h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 hd590300_2    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.10               h9b69904_4    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2  
libgcc-ng                 13.2.0               h807b86a_5    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            11.2.0               h00389a5_1  
libgfortran5              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libglib                   2.68.4               h3e27bee_0    conda-forge
libgomp                   13.2.0               h807b86a_5    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 hd590300_2    conda-forge
libllvm11                 11.1.0               h9e868ea_6  
libllvm14                 14.0.6               hef93074_0  
libnghttp2                1.52.0               ha637b67_1  
libpng                    1.6.42               h2797004_0    conda-forge
libpq                     12.15                h37d81fd_1  
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0  
libssh2                   1.10.0               h37d81fd_2  
libstdcxx-ng              13.2.0               h7e041cc_5    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.5.0                h6adf6a1_2    conda-forge
libuuid                   1.41.5               h5eee18b_0  
libuv                     1.47.0               hd590300_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.2                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.15                 h7f8727e_0  
libxkbcommon              1.0.3                he3ba5ed_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.12               h72842e0_0    conda-forge
libxslt                   1.1.33               h15afd5d_2    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
lxml                      4.8.0            py38h0a891b7_2    conda-forge
markdown                  3.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.5.2            py38h06a4308_0  
matplotlib-base           3.5.2            py38hf590b9c_0  
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6            py38h06a4308_0  
mistune                   3.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2021.4.0           h06a4308_640  
mkl-service               2.4.0            py38h7f8727e_0  
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py38hd3c417c_0  
mkl_random                1.2.2            py38h51133e4_0  
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0  
mysql                     5.7.20            hf484d3e_1001    conda-forge
mysql-common              8.0.32               h14678bc_0    conda-forge
mysql-libs                8.0.32               h54cf53e_0    conda-forge
nbclassic                 1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclient                  0.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 7.16.1                   pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  5.9.2            py38h06a4308_0  
ncurses                   6.4                  h6a678d5_0  
nest-asyncio              1.6.0            py38h06a4308_0  
nettle                    3.6                  he412f7d_0    conda-forge
networkx                  3.1                      pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  6.5.6                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook-shim             0.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
nspr                      4.35                 h6a678d5_0  
nss                       3.89.1               h6a678d5_0  
numexpr                   2.8.4            py38he184ba9_0  
numpy                     1.23.0                   pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
open3d                    0.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
open3d-python             0.3.0.0                  pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.5.3.56                 pypi_0    pypi
openh264                  2.1.1                h780b84a_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.5.0                hfec8fc6_2    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1w               h7f8727e_0  
overrides                 7.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 21.3                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
patch                     2.7.6             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
pcre                      8.45                 h295c915_0  
pcre2                     10.42                hebb0a14_0  
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3  
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003  
pillow                    10.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pip                       24.0                     pypi_0    pypi
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10           py38h06a4308_1  
platformdirs              4.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
plotly                    5.19.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ply                       3.11                     py38_0  
plyfile                   1.0.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pooch                     1.7.0            py38h06a4308_0  
prometheus_client         0.14.1           py38h06a4308_0  
prompt-toolkit            3.0.43           py38h06a4308_0  
prompt_toolkit            3.0.43               hd3eb1b0_0  
protobuf                  3.20.1                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2  
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycocotools               2.0.4            py38h71d37f0_2    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pyglet                    1.5.26                   pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyopengl                  3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 3.0.9            py38h06a4308_0  
pyqt                      5.12.3           py38h578d9bd_8    conda-forge
pyqt-impl                 5.12.3           py38h0ffb2e6_8    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 4.19.18          py38h709712a_8    conda-forge
pyqtchart                 5.12             py38h7400c14_8    conda-forge
pyqtwebengine             5.12.1           py38h7400c14_8    conda-forge
pyquaternion              0.9.9                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrender                  0.1.45                   pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38h06a4308_0  
python                    3.8.11          h12debd9_0_cpython  
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2           py38h06a4308_0  
python-json-logger        2.0.7            py38h06a4308_0  
python_abi                3.8                      1_cp38    esri
pytorch                   1.10.1          py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0    pytorch
pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    pytorch
pytz                      2022.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    6.0                      pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     23.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
qt                        5.12.9               h9d6b050_2    conda-forge
qtconsole                 5.5.0            py38h06a4308_0  
qtpy                      2.4.1            py38h06a4308_0  
readline                  8.2                  h5eee18b_0  
referencing               0.33.0                   pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.27.1                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
retrying                  1.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4            py38h06a4308_0  
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1            py38h06a4308_0  
rpds-py                   0.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.8                      pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                59.5.0                   pypi_0    pypi
shapely                   1.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
sip                       6.7.12           py38h6a678d5_0  
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
smplx                     0.1.28                   pypi_0    pypi
sniffio                   1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
soupsieve                 2.3.2.post1              pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.41.2               h5eee18b_0  
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
tenacity                  8.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               2.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tinycss2                  1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0  
tomli                     2.0.1            py38h06a4308_0  
tomlkit                   0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
torchaudio                0.10.1               py38_cu113    pytorch
torchvision               0.11.2               py38_cu113    pytorch
tornado                   6.1                      pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.64.0                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.2.2.post1              pypi_0    pypi
trimesh                   3.12.5                   pypi_0    pypi
types-python-dateutil     2.8.19.20240106          pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.9.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.9.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2024.1                   pypi_0    pypi
uri-template              1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.26.9                   pypi_0    pypi
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
webcolors                 1.13                     pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
websocket-client          1.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.41.2           py38h06a4308_0  
widgetsnbextension        4.0.10                   pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.4.5                h5eee18b_0  
y-py                      0.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
ypy-websocket             0.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
zeromq                    4.3.5                h6a678d5_0  
zipp                      3.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.5                hfc55251_0    conda-forge
```